# Laravel Sacar PDF de un registro no tabla entera

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pdf

Tengo una tabla que contiene los registros de la siguiente manera y quiero que se impriman en un PDF de registro a registro los datos que contiene no que imprima todos los registros, por eso se genera un boton en la tabla que corresponde a un registro por separado.

```
            @foreach($puos as $puo)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $puo->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->puo }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->compania->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->proyecto->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->partida }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->proveedor->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->forma_pago }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->usuario->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->usuario1->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->producto->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->cantidad }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->precio_unitario }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->descuento_porcentaje }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->iva }}</td>
                <!--<td>{{ $puo->precio_total }}</td>-->
                <td>{{ $puo->descuento }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->preciounitario_descuento }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->iva_total }}</td>
                <td>{{ $puo->total }}</td>                                                            
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('puos.edit', $puo->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    <a href="{{ route('puos.destroy', $puo->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true" onclick="return confirm('¿Seguro que quieres borrarlo')"></span></a>
                    <a href="{{ route('pdfview' ,     $puo->id) }}"><button class="btn btn-c">descargar pdf</button></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

El tercer botón llama a una funcion para imprimir el PDF, lo cual realiza su función pero se queda en una página en blanco, `https://imgur.com/a/CWJCM`

En el controlador tengo esto:

```
public function imprimir($id){
    $puo= Puo::find($id);
    $view =  \View::make('pdfview', compact('puo', $puo))->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);

    return $pdf->download("pdfview.pdf");
 }
```

Y lo que imprime contiene estos datos:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header">
              <div class="box-tools">

              </div>
            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
              <table class="table table-hover">

                @foreach($puos as $puo)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ $puo->id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->puo }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->compania->nombre }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->proyecto->nombre }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->partida }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->proveedor->nombre }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->forma_pago }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->usuario->nombre }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->usuario1->nombre }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->producto->nombre }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->cantidad }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->precio_unitario }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->descuento_porcentaje }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->iva }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->descuento }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->preciounitario_descuento }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->iva_total }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $puo->total }}</td>
                </tr>
               @endforeach
              </tbody></table>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
          </div><!-- /.box -->
        </div>
 </div>
```

En el `archivo de rutas` se genera esta:

```
Route::get('pdfview', 'PuosController@imprimir');
```

Comment: En la ruta te faltaria el parametro id del registro y pasarlo al controlador, en el controlador buscar el registro en base a ese id. Pasarlo a la vista y mostrar sus propiedades.

Comment: Pero cuando le paso la ruta al controlador me dice que `missins 2 parameters`

Comment: Podrías trabajarlo así: una ruta con 2 parámetros (/imprimir/{opc}/{id}). Donde opc es la opción si se quiere ver o descargar el documento, el id es para filtrar un solo registro. La funcion puede quedar ( imprimirPdf($opc = 'download', $id = 0) ), le decimos que por defecto la opción sea descargar y el id 0 (No existe registro). Finalmente el enlace podria quedar ({{route('imprimir-pdf', ['ocp'=>'download', 'id'=>1])}}).

Comment: Entonces con estos datos filtras un solo registro (Por lo que no es necesario recorrer nada en la vista final del pdf, a menos que sea necesario en alguna propiedad), ademas de filtrar si se quiere visualizar o descargar el documento. Me comentas si pudiste solucionarlo.

Comment: Acabo de agregar tus indicaciones a mi proyecto y no funciona, te dejo en el post de arriba una separacion donde pone modificaciones 22 de Junio donde se visualizan los cambios que realice según entendi lo que me dijistes. Gracias

Comment: Tu ruta debería quedar así: Route::get('/imprimir/{opc}/{id}',array('as'=>'imprimirPdf','uses'=>'ItemController@imprimirPdf'));

Comment: En la vista que imprime simplemente no se necesita realizar los recorridos de `foreach`. Es decir, solo lo quitas eso y te imprime un determinado registro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es instalar [DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf):

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

Añades el ServiceProvider

```
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Añades el facade

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

Una vez instalado crearemos el controlador y la vista para el pdf:

Controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PuosController extends Controller
{
    public function imprimir(Request $id){

        // recuperamos el registro, usamos el namespace (\App\) si no añadiste el modelo Puo en los use
        $puo = \App\Puo::find($id);

        // creamos y almacenamos la vista
        $vista = view('nombre_vista')
                ->with('puo', $puo);

        // Generamos el pdf pasandole la vista
        $pdf =  \PDF::loadHTML($vista);

        // retornamos la salida del pdf
        return $pdf->stream('nombre.pdf');
    }
}
```

Vista para el pdf

```
<table  style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->id }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PUO</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->puo }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->compania->nombre }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre proyecto</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->proyecto->nombre }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Partida</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->partida }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Usuario</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->usuario->nombre }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Producto</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->producto->nombre }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cantidad</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->cantidad }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IVA</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->iva }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Descuento</td>
      <td>{{ $puo->descuento }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Recordar que **`DOMPDF` no se lleva bien con `bootstrap`**, por lo que es recomendable crear la vista directamente con el css que necesitemos y nada más, por otro lado si solo vas a traer un registro de la tabla no necesitas el `@foreach`.

Eliminé algunas columnas de las que pusiste en tu vista para simplificar el ejemplo.

Obviamente asumo que conoces como crear y utilizar las rutas necesarias en Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Tengo una solución, un poco mezcla de una de las respuesta de los compañeros.

En el archivo de `rutas`lo he configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::get('puos/{id}/pdfview', [
'uses' => 'PuosController@imprimir',
'as'   => 'puos.pdfview'
]); 
Route::get('pdfview',array('as'=>'pdfview','uses'=>'ItemController@pdfview'));
Route::get('imprimirPdf',array('as'=>'imprimirPdf','uses'=>'ItemController@imprimirPdf'));
```

Y en el `Index`de mi tabla `PUO`el botón quedo asi:

```
<a href="{{ route('puos.pdfview' ,     $puo->id) }}"><button class="btn btn-c">descargar pdf</button></a>
```

La función `Imprimir` en `PuosController`

```
    public function imprimir($id){
    $puo= Puo::find($id);
    $view =  \View::make('pdfview', compact('puo', $puo))->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);

    return $pdf->download("pdfview.pdf");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

primero cambia el boton de descargar el pdf. en vez de route usa url para que vaya a un controlador

```
<a href="{{url('pdfview' , $puo->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-c">descargar pdf</button></a>
```

ahora tu ruta por ejemplo

```
 Route::get('pdfview', 'ItemController@imprimir');
```

y en el controlador haz lo siguiente:

```
public function imprimir($id){


    $pou= Pou::find($id);



    $view =  \View::make('//aqui ingresa la direccion donde esta los datos a imprimir', compact('pou', $puo))->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);
    return $pdf->download("Data de pou");



     }
```

Comment: Creo que esta casi listo, al darle a imprimri ya no me suelta error, se queda así: `https://imgur.com/a/CWJCM` es decir, creo que ya esta recogiendo bien los datos pero algo minimo debe de fallar para que no imprima.

Comment: Acabo  de realizar modificaciones en el POST para que veas como esta llendo

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia es que utilices el paquete de [Barryvdh Laravel DomPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).

Además que utilices el [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding) para inyectar directamente tu modelo en el controlador. Laravel ya se encarga de gestionar si el modelo existe y de generar los códigos de errores correspondientes.

Para el binding en el `boot` del `RouteServiceProvider` incorpora:

```
Route::model('pou', App\Pou::class);
```

Y en las rutas:

```
Route::get('pdfview/{pou}', 'PuosController@imprimir');
```

Luego en el controlador podrás definir directamente el objeto y con el paquete de `Barryvdh` son dos lineas de código:

```
public function imprimir(Pou $pou)
{
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview', ['pou' => $pou]);
    return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Me ocurre lo mismo que con la respuesta del otro compañero me redirige a una página en blanco y no carga ningun pdf

Comment: Pues entonces es posible que esté generando algún error, comprueba el access.log, error.log y laravel.log. Además asegúrate que no está el navegador bloqueando la descarga y prueba a poner la URL en un evento javascript de la siguiente forma:

`document.getElementById("boton-descarga").onclick = function(){ window.location = '{{ route("pdfview", $puo)  }}'; `