# Como visualizar con dompdf en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Buenos dias, tengo un problema no se me puede visualizar el pdf y no me muestra error
Este es mi controller de matricula

```
  $reporte_mat= new PdfController();
  $reporte_mat->crear_reporte_matricula(1);
```

Este mi controlador PdfController()

```
      public function crearPDF($datos,$vistaurl,$tipo)
{

    $data = $datos;
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $view =  \View::make($vistaurl, compact('data','date'))->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view)->setPaper('a4', 'portrait'); 

    if($tipo==1){return $pdf->stream('reporte');}
    if($tipo==2){return $pdf->download('reporte.pdf'); }
}

public function crear_reporte_matricula($tipo){

 $vistaurl="pdf.reporte_comprob_mat";
 $user=User::all();
  return $this->crearPDF($user, $vistaurl,$tipo);
}
```

Comment: Seguro que no te está generando error? Echale un vistazo a esta respuesta:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103908/laravel-sacar-pdf-de-un-registro-no-tabla-entera/105978#105978

Comment: si tengo instalado, cuando creo un boton y llamo crear_reporte_matricula(tipo) si sale el reporte, pero cuando lo intento hacer desde el controlador matricula no me presenta el reporte

Comment: **cuando creo un boton y llamo crear_reporte_matricula(tipo) si sale el reporte** a qué te refieres con esto? Cómo tienes las rutas? Qué versión de laravel estas usando? Intenta completar la pregunta, no queda claro.